# Matplotlib set size of plotting area for printing

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, imshow

Suppose I have an figure of given size in pixels (1344 x 1920 in that case), see below. I want to save that figure to a pdf file and eventually print it to a physical sheet of paper. When printing, I need to have the dimensions on paper of the plotting area fixed in centimeters. The final image on paper needs to be say 20cm in width and 14cm in height. I will print it without the axis so it will be only the **interior** of the black square representing the axis, I don't care about the figure size in total including the labels etc.

[image]

Cheers

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would help a lot if you gave some example code.

Comment: I used fig.set_size_inches but this would set the complete figure size not the drawing area size. To get to have simply a figure like above is not really interesting in this case I think since one could just to plt.plot([1, 100], [1, 100]) for example and work from there on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib's `figsize` to set the size of the plot in inches (not sure if there is a way to do it in cm).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
#...

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8)) #will make the figure 10 by 8 inches
```

Comment: Is the size of the ticks, labels etc, included in this dimension or does that really set only the interior size of the area where the plot is being drawn (i.e. inside the black rectangle in the example given in the question)?

Comment: @Matt No, axes are not included in the size (I just tried it).

Comment: I tested it out as well and the problem is that the size specified (10, 8) is really the figure size which is the drawing area PLUS a padding. It is true that the size of the drawing area does not change when adding axis, ticks or titles because matplotlib puts all of this inside the padding area, so the bunny would appear in the same (wrong!) size on the paper. I don't care about the total size of the figure but I need the area within the axis to be a certain size. One dirty hack would be to check how much padding matplotlib puts and account for that when creating the figure.

Comment: I think one solution might be to have no axis, titles in your figure and then set out_fig.savefig(path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0) when saving. I will test it out and report, looks promising for now.

Comment: You can do that. You can also make your figure size 20% larger in each dimension and use the bottom, top, left, right to set the size of the axes